# Why is my output incorrect when in base 16

Tags: c++, radix

I am to write a program that lets me convert any number into any base.

My program currently outputs "1669" for 366 base 16 when the correct output is 16E. Where is my code screwing up?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int iInter, iBase, iRemainder, i, iMax;
    int rgiTable[25];
    char cAgain;

    do
    {
        do
        {
            cout << "Enter an integer greater than zero" << endl;
            cin >> iInter;

            cout << "Enter a base between the numbers 2 and 16" << endl;
            cin >> iBase;

            if (iInter < 0)
                cout << "Enter a new Integer" << endl;
            if (iBase < 2 || iBase > 16)
                cout<< "Enter a new base" << endl;
        } while (iInter < 0 || (iBase < 2 || iBase > 16));

        for (i = 0; iInter > 0; i++)
        {
            iRemainder = iInter % iBase;
            iInter = iInter / iBase;

            if (iRemainder == 0)
                rgiTable[i] = 0;
            if (iRemainder == 1)
                rgiTable[i] = 1;
            if (iRemainder == 2)
                rgiTable[i] = 2;
            if (iRemainder == 3)
                rgiTable[i] = 3;
            if (iRemainder == 4)
                rgiTable[i] = 4;
            if (iRemainder == 5)
                rgiTable[i] = 5;
            if (iRemainder == 6)
                rgiTable[i] = 6;
            if (iRemainder == 7)
                rgiTable[i] = 7;
            if (iRemainder == 8)
                rgiTable[i] = 8;
            if (iRemainder == 9)
                rgiTable[i] = 9;
            if (iRemainder == 10)
                rgiTable[i] = 'A';
            if (iRemainder == 11)
                rgiTable[i] = 'B';
            if (iRemainder == 12)
                rgiTable[i] = 'C';
            if (iRemainder == 13)
                rgiTable[i] = 'D';
            if (iRemainder == 14)
                rgiTable[i] = 'E';
            if (iRemainder == 15)
                rgiTable[i] = 'F';

            iMax = i;
        }

        while (iMax >= 0)
        {
            cout << rgiTable[iMax];
            iMax--;
        }
        cout << endl;

        cout << "Do you wish to enter more data? y/n" << endl;
        cin >> cAgain;

    } while (cAgain == 'y'|| cAgain == 'Y');

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: PLEASE pay attention to how your question looks in the preview before posting. You did mention the problem, but consider [how awful it looked](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/26623310/1)...it took effort to [make it reasonable](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/26623310/4).  That should be effort a question asker takes. [Learn Markdown](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) *and pay attention to the preview* before posting. Don't ask your question in code comments; it should be in the surrounding text and clear. Please heed the preview in the future--that's what we all see!

Comment: ...and @DennisMeng It isn't helpful to give DO and FOR and WHILE braces their own line.  Collapsing vertical space in code samples is more helpful for people trying to skim code in a vertical browser than some minor horizontal space in array indexing, all things being equal.  Both are best, I guess.  Editing is virtuous, but if you're going to merge, then merge to tighten up the whole thing.  Also, I prefer "here is the code" and then "here is the flawed output" to having to see the bad output before the code, personally.

Comment: @HostileFork As far as do/for/while and whether or not they should be on the same line; I've always understood it to be a matter of style. If the OP adheres to putting them on the next line and sticks with it through the entire post, I'm not going to go through and change it for them. I personally like them on the same line too, but I'm not going to edit a post to make their code that way unless 1) it's already that way or 2) they're doing some of both.

Comment: As for the array indexing, I did that change purely because I've almost never seen it with a space; if both with and without a space were commonplace, I wouldn't have changed that either.

Comment: @DennisMeng When code is reformatted on StackOverflow it should be for a reason. ["completely illegible"](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/26623310/1) or unnecessary vertical space count. *(I'm still often confused about how many stray newlines there are in code by people who seem to never use whitespace anywhere else in their program.)*  Collapsing vertical space and wiping out horizontal and vertical scroll bars where possible for code samples on current media devices serves a goal. I think arguments on the OPs style must be weighed based on the awareness the OP demonstrates of the medium.

Comment: I agree with "code has to be reformatted for a reason" but disagree with changing up where for/do/while have their left curly braces based on the rest of the code. At the same time though, you clearly feel more strongly than I do about this. If you really feel bothered by the formatting enough to make those left curly braces be on the same line again, I'm not going to revert it back to having them on the next line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you print a digit using

```
cout<< rgiTable[iMax];
```

you are printing an integer. When that integer value is equal to `E`, you get the ASCII value of `E`, which is 69.

Instead of

```
int rgiTable [25];
```

you should use

```
char rgiTable [25];
```

In the `while` loop, use the characters `'0'` - `'9'` instead of numbers `0` - `9`.

You can simplify the logic using:

```
  for ( i=0; iInter > 0; i++)
  {
     iRemainder = iInter % iBase;
     iInter = iInter / iBase;

     if ( iRemainder < 10 )
     {
        rgiTable [i] = iRemainder + '0';
     }
     else 
     {
        rgiTable [i] = iRemainder + 'A' - 10;
     }

     iMax = i;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The [ASCII code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_characters) for the capital E character is 69. You have to decide whether the array `rgiTable` should store integers 0 through 16 or ASCII codes '0' through 'E'. If you decide on the latter design, you can declare it as `char rgiTable[25]` to ensure that the array elements are formatted properly when output to `cout`.

By the way, it's a good idea to initialize all your local variables. In this case, you have a bug when `iInter` is 0: `iMax` is never initialized, so the program outputs garbage data.